# User/organization relationship with mongoid

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I have a relationship like this:

Organization:

```
class Organization
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :name, type: String
  field :email, type: String

  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

User:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include ActiveModel::SecurePassword

  has_secure_password

  #Fields
  field :nick, type: String
  field :name, type: String
  field :email, type: String
  field :password_digest, type: String #for bcrypt-ruby

  #Validations
  ## Presence
  validates :nick, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true
  validates :password, presence: true, :on => :create

  #Uniqueness
  validates :nick, uniqueness: true
  validates :email, uniqueness: true

  #Relations
  has_many :documents, dependent: :delete
  has_many :storages, dependent: :delete

  has_and_belongs_to_many :organizations
end
```

I can save the organization and the users. The relation works fine, but now I want to add an Owner to organization, which is a User too.
I tried with `has_one :user, as: :owner` but didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your organization.rb:

```
has_one :owner, class_name: "User", inverse_of :owns
```

and add this to your user.rb:

```
belongs_to :owns, class_name: "Organization", inverse_of :owner
```

Or, if you prefer, you could reverse the logic and put the `has_one` in your user class and the `belongs_to` in your organization. It depends on the logic of your application, obviously.